# fine-uploader uploaded file list css formatting. Can't get to be same width as line

Tags: css, html-lists, fine-uploader

I've been messing around with the css of the fineuploader 3.8, but no matter what I do I can't seem to get the file upload li to match the width of the separator line that's part of the control.  Any thoughts?

The ugly fuchsia is just me messing around with the qq-upload-list li.qq-upload-success css setting, so I know that I'm dealing with potentially the correct item.  I believe its container is the qq-upload-list, but I'm not sure what I need to modify.  Thanks!

HTML in my partial view (MVC4).  Originally I had everything in DIVs, but I couldn't get anything to be 100% within the page.  I got sick of dealing with it, so I went back to tables.  Yeah, I know, not the best thing to use.  Let's move past this to my question.

```
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr valign="top">
    <td width="100%">
        <div id="files-upload"></div>   

        <div>                                
            @Html.Partial("_PreviouslyUploadedFiles") 
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's the CSS, most of it is stock 3.8

```
  .qq-upload-list {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;    
list-style: none; }

.qq-upload-list li {
margin: 0;
padding: 9px;
line-height: 15px;
font-size: 16px;
background-color: #FFF0BD;}

.qq-upload-file, .qq-upload-spinner, .qq-upload-size, .qq-upload-cancel, .qq-upload-retry, .qq-upload-failed-text, .qq-upload-finished, .qq-upload-delete {
margin-right: 12px;}
```

Here's the specific success block after an upload.  I added the 100% and now the width goes BEYOND the line.

```
  .qq-upload-list li.qq-upload-success {
background-color: #5DA30C;    
width: 100%;
color: #FFFFFF;}
```

This picture shows the success block WITHOUT the width 100%

[image: css formatting issue]

This picture shows the success block WITH the width 100%, changed back to default colors on this one.

[image]

Comment: You will need to show the code you have attempted to use in order for anyone to help.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `width`, just a thought?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have attempted.

Comment: Edit on the original question, added html, css, and examples of output after changes as displayed in IE9.  Please see above.

Comment: You didn't modify the fineuploader.css file, I hope, did you?

Comment: I'm surprised you're telling me to not modify it, within reason, of course.  I was changing colors, etc. to better match the current styling where it'll be used. Am I missing something here because where else would I change these kinds of things? As a stock css file I still see this discrepancy in IE9, haven't tried it in Chrome, FF, etc.

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice to locally change any code in a 3rd-party library.  This is guaranteed to make upgrading and troubleshooting a nightmare.  You can and should contribute your custom CSS rules via your own CSS file.  If you want your CSS rules to override some of Fine Uploader's CSS rules, there are well-established ways to do that, such as increasing the specificity of your selectors.  As far as your specific styling issue is concerned, I'm not sure I will be able to help much as I'm a bit buried and this is much more of a CSS question than a Fine Uploader question.

Comment: For me this worked making the line and the uploaded color bar equal:

.qq-upload-list li {
    **margin: 1px -7px 1px -1px;**
    padding: 7px;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #FFF0BD;
    }

Comment: If this solved your problem, please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I feel like an idiot.  I didn't realize that my view (.cshtml) where the upload control is located also includes a tiny partial view that had been modified (an [hr] had been added).  I had no idea where this [hr] was coming from, and didn't think anyone had modified the partial view, so in my mind it must be part of the upload control.  Sorry, my whole question is moot now.  My bad.  :)